# Обобщение для операций с таблицами в одной модели Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics

Есть много таблиц в одной модели, созданной при помощи Code First. С каждой из них нужно проделать одинаковые операции. Я уверен, что есть способ как-то обобщить. 
Например, если в одной модели db есть три таблицы Shops, Products и Orders, как вместо такого:

```
Shop shop = new Shop();
db.Shops.Add(shop);

Product product = new Product();
db.Products.Add(product);

Order order = new Order();
db.Orders.Add(order);
```

написать что-то в духе:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  T temp = new T();
  db.T.Add(temp);
}
```

Как обобщить именно само название таблицы в DbContext например в строчке db.Shops. ... ? Или как это сделать по-другому, чтобы не повторять код? Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Можно спокойно использовать db.Add(new T())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашел решение: вместо

```
db.Shops
```

надо написать:

```
db.Set<Shop>()
```

И тогда уже можно обобщить.